# how to use dynamically created checkboxes inside a table

Tags: php, android, mysql, checkbox

my code above creates a table with checkboxes and textviews inside.
the count and the values comes from a MySQL database over php-json.
It works all fine.
Problem:
In the onClickSenden function, I want to check step by step every created checkbox unchecked or checked and do some code depending on.

Its not possible to setId(i), coz "i" is an Iterator and not int.

can u help me?

```
public class EinbuchungActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {
    String data = "";
    TableLayout tl;
    TableRow tr;
    TextView label;
    CheckBox cb; 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_einbuchen);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvNutzer);
        tv.setText(MainActivity.username);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvKst);
        tv2.setText(MainActivity.kst);

        tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.maintable);

        final GetDataFromDB getdb = new GetDataFromDB();
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                data = getdb.getDataFromDB();
                System.out.println(data);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<Users> users = parseJSON(data);
                        addData(users);                     
                    }
                });

            }
        }).start();
    }

    public ArrayList<Users> parseJSON(String result) {
        //Array-Liste erstellen mit definierter Arrayliste
        ArrayList<Users> users = new ArrayList<Users>();
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            //Array-Liste mit Daten füllen
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                Users user = new Users();
                user.setEan(json_data.getString("ean"));
                user.setName(json_data.getString("name"));
                user.setBetriebszahl(json_data.getString("betriebsdatenalt"));
                users.add(user);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());  
        }
        return users;
    }

    void addHeader(){
        /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
        tr = new TableRow(this);

        /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
        label = new TextView(this);
        label.setText("Inventarnummer");
        label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //label.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(label,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

        /** Creating Qty Button **/
        TextView place = new TextView(this);
        place.setText("Name");
        place.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        place.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
        //place.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.setMargins(0, 5, 5, 5);
        //Ll.setPadding(10, 5, 5, 5);
        Ll.addView(place,params);
        tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textview to tablerow.

         // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes" })
    public void addData(ArrayList<Users> users) {
        addHeader();    
         for (Iterator i = users.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
            Users p = (Users) i.next();
            /** Create a TableRow dynamically **/
            tr = new TableRow(this);
            /** Creating a Checkbox to add to the row **/
            CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
            cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            cb.setText(p.getEan());
            LinearLayout Ll1 = new LinearLayout(this);
            Ll1.addView(cb);
            tr.addView((View)Ll1); // Adding CheckBox to tablerow.  
            /** Creating a TextView to add to the row **/
            label = new TextView(this);
            label.setText(p.getName());
            label.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            label.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
            label.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            LinearLayout Ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            params.setMargins(5, 2, 2, 2);
            Ll.addView(label,params);
            tr.addView((View)Ll); // Adding textView to tablerow.

             // Add the TableRow to the TableLayout
            tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        }

    }



    public void onClickSenden (View view) {


    }


}
```

Comment: I already gave you complete code for that in your other post. But you did not even react. That is not the way to go.

Comment: i used ur code, but it didnt worked, and its not the complete code. i tried to change to my code and gave it up

Comment: That is also not the way to go. You should have continued there with showing what you had tried. Then asked for further help there.  If you really had given up you would not have asked the same here again.

Comment: thanks for ur help. but you see i changed the code to my real code and need now help here. not with the "old" code. i am sorry for all the complicated things, and ofc i dont give up ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(this);
cb.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Set checkbox id or a tag while creating it.

```
cb.setTag(someIdentifier);
```

then use the method

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (v.getTag.equals(someIdentifier)){
                    //do stuff here
                  }    
                }
```

Comment: Ill get getTag cannot be resolved or is not a field on the code @Override 
public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (v.getTag.equals(someIdentifier)){
                    //do stuff here
                  }    
                }